# window.location.href returns HttpContext.Current.Request.Path as"/"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a filter that fetches a the current request path. For certain cases I have used

```
window.location.href =@Url.Action("Action","Controller").
```

Generally `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` returns `Controller/Action` but in case of `window.location.href` it always returns `"/"`. Could I use something other than `window.location.href` to redirect so that I can retrieve the proper path?

Comment: The javascript `window.location.href` is completely indifferent to `@Url.Action("Action","Controller")`.

Comment: I assumed the same and tried to give an absolute path instead of @Url.Action but it returned the same result

Comment: Can you give an example URL? Is `/` correct? Incorrect? I can't tell. You're also not quoting `@Url.Action("Action","Controller")`.

Comment: @Url.Action("Home", "BuildQuery") translates to localhost/BuildQuery/Home normally, but in this case it translates to "/"

Comment: It should give you the relative path. What is wrong with that ?

Comment: It isn't giving a relative path.. That's what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.href` expects a JavaScript string but your code renders invalid JS as the URL generated by `Url.Action(...)` is not surrounded by either apostrophes or quotation marks.

The correct code would be

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")';
```

However, I recommend [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode) as a completely fail-safe solution:

```
window.location.href = @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("Action","Controller"), addDoubleQuotes: true);
```

Comment: I am doing it in the way you mentioned. Anyways will give httputility a try. Haven't tried it in that form. I cannot post the code as I do not have access to stack overflow on my work machine